# Disable creation of _AUD tables with Hibernate Envers for entities?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

How to disable creation of _AUD tables with Hibernate Envers for entities ? 
I want do custom audit just by using the AuditListeners instead of allowing control to Hibernate to create tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: just do not mark your entities with `@Audited` annotation.

Long one: you're probably mixing these concepts. Envers has nothing to do with `EntityListeners`, that is a hibernate concept. If you want to manually implement auditing you're probably don't need envers after all, just hibernate will be enough.