# How to prevent Hibernate Envers for creating Audit tables?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

In my case, i have a dependency to a module that implementing envers in its domains (its domains were annotated with @Audited). When i imported that module in my pom.xml and run my app, envers automatically creating audit tables based on its domains. My question, how can i prevent Envers for creating audited tables after the domains were annotated with @Audited? Is there any solution like adding a configuration in application.properties file or something like that?

```
  org.hibernate.envers.table_creation = false
```

Comment: so you want to say that your module `A` has `@Audited` annotation, but your module `B` does not? yet, the audited tables are created for *all* entities? I don't get it

Comment: or you want to crate the tables yourself without hibernate generating them? this is really confusing now

Comment: I just dont want hibernate envers creating audit tables from module A without removing @Audited annotation on its domains. Can I do that?

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: i found same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112539/disable-creation-of-aud-tables-with-hibernate-envers-for-entities

thanks @Eugene

Answer (score 0):

If you're importing a dependency that uses Envers but you do not require the tables or its functionality in your environment, you can easily disable Envers via a simple hibernate setting

```
hibernate.integration.envers.enabled=false
```

This should prevent Envers from bootstrapping and building any envers schema and it should also prevent the event listeners from being registered when entity model events fire where we track changes and generate the audit entries.